# AppleScript : How do i make AppleScript say a selected phrase when pressing a specific key?

Tags: applescript

How do i make AppleScript say a selected phrase when pressing a specific key?

For example, if the key " S " is pressed i want the same thing to happen when you type :
Say "s"

This is my code for now :

```
property this_text : "EMail"
tell application "Mail"
activate
say "loading complete, type your mail message now"
display dialog "Type your Email message." default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2
set the this_text to text returned of the result
set this_message to make new outgoing message at end of outgoing messages with properties {content:this_text, visible:true}
tell this_message
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:""}
    say "to who do you want to send this mail?"
end tell

end tell

say "don't forget to add an subject"
```

But even with QuickSilver i can't seem to figure it out.

It is an Application for an Friend of mine which can't see good, so now i want the Application to say which key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The following should help you to do this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/665313?start=0&tstart=0

Also, as the command you want is 'say', here's the documentation for it: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as304.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks, But i couldn't find how to assign it to an key. I know how to use the 'Say' command, but not how to assign it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a problem, take a look at: http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/run-applescripts-with-keyboard-shortcuts.php

Comment: Not a problem. If it worked out accepting the answer (and/or upvoting) is a great way to show your thanks! If you're stuck with anything else please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Since my reputation is under 15 i can't vote up, but when i'll reach 15 i'll sure vote up for you :)